# install php 8.1 manjaro

Tags: php, manjaro

i am trying to install php 8.1 in manjaro but i am getting errors.

This I am doing:

```
[home_the_archphp_arch]
Server = https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/el:/archphp/Arch/$arch

key=$(curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:el:archphp/Arch/$(uname -m)/home_el_archphp_Arch.key)
fingerprint=$(gpg --quiet --with-colons --import-options show-only --import --fingerprint <<< "${key}" | awk -F: '$1 == "fpr" { print $10 }')
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --add - <<< "${key}"
pacman-key --lsign-key "${fingerprint}"
```

But when running

```
sudo pacman -S php81-apache
```

He tells me this:

```
  error: php81: signature of "home:el OBS Project <home:el@build.opensuse.org>" is invalid
:: The file /var/cache/pacman/pkg/php81-8.1.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupt (invalid or corrupt package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
```

I've been looking but I didn't find anything.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should update the package manager with available packages after adding the repository.